# Event being triggered even though form field is $pristine

Tags: angularjs

My form has two input fields as below:

```
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"  placeholder="Enter password"  class="form-control" />
<input type="password" name="password_confirm" ng-model="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password" class="form-control" validate-equals="password" />
```

Please match the passwords

Expected:
The error below the second input should trigger only if the second input field is $dirty and not matching the first field

However that behavior is not achieved.

```
app.directive('validateEquals', function(){

  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      function validateEqual(value) {
        var valid = (value === scope.$eval(attrs.validateEquals));
        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('equal', valid);
        return valid ? value : undefined;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(validateEqual);
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(validateEqual);

      scope.$watch(attrs.validateEquals, function(){
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue)
      });

    }

  };

})
```

Please check the [**full plnkr here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zGfeU8nDMY6c6pJj4DX2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this watch:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.validateEquals, function(){
   ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue)
});
```

At startup that `$watch` fires, calling `$setViewValue()` on the input which you've set the attribute `validateEquals` on (specifically, `password_confirm`).  Calling `$setViewValue` results in that field being marked `$dirty` (since you're setting the field to something).

I'm not seeing a reason for that `$watch`, which just sets the `viewValue` to whatever it already was.  So unless I'm missing something, you should be fine removing it- thus solving your problem.

Working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4QAjucKLVa2MWAjAcGcf?p=preview

Comment: Your plnkr is working but this pushes me further into more confusion. Isin't $setViewValue responsible for triggers the functions in $parsers and $formatters arrays ? If we remove the $watch, what is triggerign them ?

Comment: The viewValue is already set by Angular as part of calling $formatters when the model value changes.  You don't need do it manually unless you want to do something special (for example adding a '$' to a currency field- leaving the model value without a $ but the view with)

Comment: @KayakDate ..pls confirm that all functions within $parsers and $formatters are executed everytime the model associated with it updates ?

Comment: When the modelValue changes then $parsers are called- the result of which is put into the viewValue (then $render is called).  If the viewValue is changed then $formatters are called and the result placed into the modelValue.(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)  Does that help?

Comment: One more note, you likely only need to add this validation to $parsers.  That checks the case where the user types something into the input.  You'd add it to $formatters if you might update the value programatically- i.e. calling setViewValue - and want that checked.

Comment: @KayakDave..had read the docs before posting the question but wasn't clear about a lot of things.. Your comments have helped quiet a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66297/discussion-between-james-hans-and-kayakdave).